# Rewrite Question

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I'm having troubles with creating my rewrite. I've been searching here (and other sites) for an example, but so far, no luck.

My testing site is:

```
../?attachment_id=3027&attachment_category=yosemite
```

I would like it to display this:

```
../portfolio/yosemite/3027
```

or even these:

```
../portfolio/3027/yosemite/

../3027/yosemite/
```

I tried to add this to my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?attachment_id=$1&attachment_category=$2 [L]
```

but obviously that didn't work. Any ideas would be appreciated as I continue to find an answer.

**Edit #1**

Tried this, but no luck.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
function my_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    array_push($query_vars, 'attachment_id', 'attachment_category');
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'my_rewrite_rules_array' );
function my_rewrite_rules_array( $rules ) {
    $my_rules = array();
    $my_rules['portfolio/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$'] = 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[1]&attachment_category=$matches[2]';
        return $my_rules + $rules;
    }

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_flush_rules' );
function my_flush_rules() {
if (!$rules = get_option('rewrite_rules'))
    $rules = array();

if (!isset($rules['portfolio/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$'])) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle rewrites in a plugin or in your theme's `functions.php`.

I think something like this might work (assuming `attachment_id` and `attachment_category` are registered tags/variables.

```
<?php 
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_rule');
function myplugin_rewrite_rule() {

    add_rewrite_rule('^portfolio/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
        'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[1]&attachment_category=matches[2]',
        'top');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I know the `attachment_id` is valid because that's from WP. The `attachment_category` is from a plugin (Media Library Assistant) I'm using.

Comment: Try going to your Admin / Permalinks section and selecting "Save" after your plugin has been activated. I never had any luck flushing myself.

Comment: Thanks thornomad, but still not working.